# Redis TTL vs "allkeys-lru" eviction policy

Tags: redis

I have a question on Redis cache's behavior. Kindly clarify -

Say, for a key "xyz" if the TTL is set to 15 minutes.
And, if its eviction policy in server level is  set to "allkeys-lru". Does expired items(cause of TTL) EXPIRE or WAIT until the memory is full?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The eviction policy only applies to what happens when you exceed the max memory. As long as you're within your memory limits, volatile keys will expire when they should be expired.

Once your memory is full, an LRU algorithm kicks in, evicting least recently used keys. In `allkeys-lru`, it doesn't matter whether a key is expired or not and what is the TTL - the least used items will be evicted. In `volatile-lru` only expiring keys will be evicted using this algorithm.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe it's a rhetorical question, but if all my keys are volatile (they have a timeout) both `volatile-lru` and `allkeys-lru` policies have the same effect, right?

Comment: How the Redis  recognizes LRU keys?

Comment: @AminShojaei it samples a bunch of keys for their access time IIRC.

Comment: What happens if there are no volatile keys? it will fallback to allkeys  to run the lru algorithm?

Comment: @silva96 no, keys will continue to accumulate until Redis runs out of memory and starts refusing to store new keys (generating an OOM error)

Comment: This is not quite true (anymore), LRU items do get evicted even when memory is not full.
See https://www.pankajtanwar.in/blog/how-redis-expires-keys-a-deep-dive-into-how-ttl-works-internally-in-redis